# Why is current_user giving me an error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my create method in the Videos controller, this line works:

```
@video = Video.new(params[:video])
```

However, I want to assign the video to the user, so I use this line which gives me an error:

```
@video = current_user.videos.new(params[:video])
```

This is the error:

```
NoMethodError in VideosController#create

undefined method `videos' for nil:NilClass
```

I have this in my User model:

```
has_many :videos
```

And this in my Video model:

```
belongs_to :user
```

This is in my application_controller file:

```
  def current_user
    return unless session[:user_id]
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_id(session[:user_id]) 
  end

  # Make current_user available in templates as a helper
  helper_method :current_user
```

How do I fix this error? Let me know if I should post anymore code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this error only happening when the user is not logged or there's no session[:user_id]?

When not logged in:

```
@video = current_user.videos.new(params[:video])
```

...would be...

```
@video = nil.videos.new(params[:video])
```

which would give you that exact `NoMethodError`